# Why LocalDateTime formatted with zone offset?

Tags: java, java-time

Consider code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd-HH")));
}
```

The output is `2022-05-04-17` while UTC time is `2022-05-04-10`. The documentation says that `LocalDateTime` is without zone offset - so why there is 7 hour shift? (My local time zone is `+7UTC`)

Comment: Local time is local time. You need to be situated in UTC zone if you want your local time to match UTC.

Comment: LocalDateTime is your local date/time, but without information stored about what that origin zone actually was. You could parse the string "2022-01-01 00:00" into a LocalDateTime. It would represent midnight, Jan 1st *somewhere*, but without knowing the *somewhere*, you wouldn't be able to say what instant that was

Comment: @Kayaman: Well, no you don't - you just need to *specify* that you want UTC.

Comment: @JonSkeet And also there is no country that is "in UTC zone" year-round anyway (to my knowledge). UK matches UTC sometimes (GMT), but not in daylight savings (BST).

Comment: Also note that this question isn't really about *formatting*, contrary to the question title. It's about the value stored in the `LocalDateTime`.

Comment: @Michael: Indeed. Although it's entirely possible to set the system local time zone to UTC, of course.

Comment: Never ever use the no-arg `LocalDateTime.now()`. For the UTC time use `LocalDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC)` or even better `OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC)` so the obtained object also knows its own offset.

Comment: Are you required to produce that format? I am a bit worried that it may be confused since `2022-05-04-10` according to [the ISO 8601 standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) means a date at UTC offset -10:00 (10 hours behind UTC, as used in Pacific/Rarotonga, Pacific/Tahiti, Pacific/Honolulu and Pacific/Johnston time zones).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You've called `LocalDateTime.now()`, which is [documented](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#now()) as (emphasis mine):

> Obtains the current date-time from the system clock **in the default time-zone**.
>
> This will query the system clock in the default time-zone to obtain the current date-time.

The returned `LocalDateTime` doesn't "know" the UTC offset, but it's been applied already in determining the value.

If you want to get the current UTC time, you can use `LocalDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC)`. (It's possible that `LocalDateTime` isn't the most appropriate representation in that case though - we'd need to know more about what you're using it for.)